# How do I make my frames change in java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Let's say there is a button and if you will click that, a new frame will appear and so on...

Answer (score 3):

The `setVisible(true);` function is used to display a frame. Create an object of the desired frame and call this function. Something like this

```
//The applications first or the main frame
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

        private JButton myFirstButton;
        private JButton mySecondButton;

        // Constructor for a new frame

        public MainFrame {

                super("My First Button Program");

                myFirstButton = new JButton("First Frame");
                myFirstButton.setFont(new Font( "Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
                myFirstButton.setBackground(Color.red);

                mySecondButton = new JButton("New Frame");
                mySecondButton.setFont(new Font( "Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
                mySecondButton.setBackground(Color.green);

                Container c = getContentPane();
                FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT);
                c.setLayout(fl);

                c.add (myFirstButton);
                c.add (mySecondButton);

                ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();    //creation of a new Object
                myFirstButton.addActionListener(handler);          // Attach/register handler to myFirstButton
                mySecondButton.addActionListener(handler);        //Attach/register handler to mySecondButton

                setSize(400, 300);
                show();
        }


        public static void main(String [] args) {

                // Make frame
                MainFrame f = new MainFrame();

                f.addWindowListener(
                        new WindowAdapter() {
                                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

                                        // This closes the window and terminates the
                                        // Java Virtual Machine in the event that the
                                        // Frame is closed by clicking on X.
                                        System.out.println("Exit via windowClosing.");
                                        System.exit(0);
                                }
                        }
                );
        } // end of main

        // inner class for button event handling
        private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if (e.getSource() == myFirstButton) {
                                new NewFrame1();

                        }
                        if (e.getSource() == mySecondButton) {
                                new NewFrame2();
                        }
                }
        } // end of inner class
} // end of outer class
```

The frame to be opened for first button

```
//import statements here
public class NewFrame1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
        //initialises the frame and opens it
        public NewFrame1()
        {
                JButton open = new JButton("New Window");
                open.addActionListener(this);
                add(open);
                setVisible(true);
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
                //code for the new frame
        }
}
```

The frame to be opened for second button

```
//import statements here
public class NewFrame2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
        //initialises the frame and opens it
        public NewFrame2()
        {
                JButton open = new JButton("New Window");
                open.addActionListener(this);
                add(open);
                setVisible(true);
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
                //code for the new frame
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make one `JFrame` class, call it MainFrame for example, and from here open `JPanels`, that way you have a centralized place to commuincate data between different frames,popups,options dialogs ...etc

Sidenote: i recommend using an MVC design pattern

Answer (score 1):

Your usage context is unclear. Maybe what you need is a JTabbedPane ([tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html))?