# java changing JPanel on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, cardlayout

I am working on a 15 puzzle.
I need to change the JPanel in the JFrame for a new game.
The reason is that some games have 16 buttons while others have 9 or 25. Sometimes the buttons have a number, but sometimes they have pieces of a picture.
I would like to set up my JPanel, then set it into the JFrame.
The only way that I have been able to achieve this so far is to create a new JFrame, but that outputs a new window.
Is it possible to change the JPanel in the JFrame in java?

Comment: Google `Swing CardLayout Tutorial`. First hit.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218155/how-do-i-change-jpanel-inside-a-jframe-on-the-fly

Comment: Or look at my answer and code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8027858/522444), or this one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6893133/522444).

Comment: Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11803735/522444) is kind of colorful, and shows swapping views with either JButtons or a JComboBox.